# Finding divisors with canonical singularities in a moving linear system

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, minimal-model-program

I apologize if the question is too naive or trivial:

We know that any reduced divisor in a smooth variety has Gorenstein singularities. However, I don't know if there's a cone theorem for Gorenstein varieties.

Let $|L|$ be a moving linear system on a smooth projective variety $X$. Can we find some $D \in |L|$ such that $D$ has canonical singularities? (Ideally I want something to which Cone Theorem applies). Thanks in advance.

Comment: If "moving" means "movable" (i.e. no fixed component), the answer is no: take the pencil $\lambda (X^3+Y^3)+\mu Z^3=0$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$.